# Continuum limit of the discrete entropy expression

Tags: entropy

I understood where the expression of the entropy
$S=-k_B\sum p\log p$ comes from. Now I am trying to take this expression to its continuum limit and I want to get the form
$$S=-k_B\int\rho \log\rho$$

I imagined that we were in a 6N dimensional phase space so that I replace $p$ into $\rho \delta\Gamma$ where $\delta\Gamma$ is a small volume, we then have
$$S=-k_B\sum (\rho\delta\Gamma)\log(\rho\delta\Gamma)$$

There exists an $\log\delta\Gamma$ in this summation that seems to be inevitable, so my question is

1. Am I on the right track? Can I take the continuum limit in this way?
2. If not, what should be the appropriate way to do so?

Comment: The sum is usually over finite number of terms, and is thus finite. The trouble with going to the "continuum limit" is that number of terms goes to infinity, and the sum(integral) is not guaranteed to produce a finite number anymore.